# Deleting Numeric Duplicate Rows Only?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have two sheets in a workbook. They are imported (connected) from two text file reports. Right now the code I'll post below deletes all duplicates between the two sheets and leaves me with the first sheet (today) with just unique rows left. The problem is Column A, which I use to compare and delete contains words on some lines (like "Category") and numbers on other lines. The only duplicates I really need deleted are the numeric duplicates. I would prefer the words get ignored. Is there a way to delete duplicate rows with numeric values and ignore letter values? I haven't been able to find anything and I honestly don't do this stuff often.

```
Sub CleanDupes()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim targetArray, searchArray, targetRange As Range, x As Long
           
    'Update these 4 lines if your target and search ranges change
    Dim TargetSheetName As String: TargetSheetName = "Today"
    Dim TargetSheetColumn As String: TargetSheetColumn = "A"
    Dim SearchSheetName As String: SearchSheetName = "Yesterday"
    Dim SearchSheetColumn As String: SearchSheetColumn = "A"

    'Load target array
    With Sheets(TargetSheetName)
        Set targetRange = .Range(.Range(TargetSheetColumn & "12"), _
                .Range(TargetSheetColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        targetArray = targetRange
    End With
    'Load Search Array
    With Sheets(SearchSheetName)
        searchArray = .Range(.Range(SearchSheetColumn & "12"), _
                .Range(SearchSheetColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With


    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'Populate dictionary from search array
    If IsArray(searchArray) Then
        For x = 1 To UBound(searchArray)
            If Not dict.exists(searchArray(x, 1)) Then
                dict.Add searchArray(x, 1), 1
            End If
        Next
    Else
        If Not dict.exists(searchArray) Then
            dict.Add searchArray, 1
        End If
    End If

    'Delete rows with values found in dictionary
    If IsArray(targetArray) Then
        'Step backwards to avoid deleting the wrong rows.
        For x = UBound(targetArray) To 1 Step -1
            If dict.exists(targetArray(x, 1)) Then
                targetRange.Cells(x).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Else
        If dict.exists(targetArray) Then
            targetRange.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Check if the value `IsNumeric` before adding it to the dictionary?

Comment: Does anybody no the differences between `IsNumeric(...)` and `Vartype(...) = vbDouble`? There shouldn't be too many.